# Views will not use pathauto URL Alias when listing programatically saved nodes

Tags: 7, views, path-aliases

I am programatically saving nodes, and everything is working fine. Pathauto is working correctly as well and generating aliases based on my url alias configurations.

However, when Views creates a list of the new nodes, it uses node/xx instead of the existing url alias.  Anyone know why this could be happening? All caches have been cleared, cron ran, etc. Here is the code

```
$node = new stdClass();
    //set other defaults
    node_object_prepare($node);

    $node->type = $page_data['content_type'];
    $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $page_data['description'];
    $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['summary'] = text_summary($page_data['description']);
    $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['format']  = 'filtered_html';
    $node->title = $page_data['title'];
    $node->field_product_price[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $page_data['price'];
    $node->field_item_location[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['postal_code'] = $page_data['zipcode'];
    $node->uid = "1";
    $node->status = 1;
    $node->active = 1;
    $node->pathauto_perform_alias = TRUE;

$node->field_product_images[LANGUAGE_NONE] = $images;
unset($images);


$node->field_baby_clothes_category[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'] = $page_data['category']; 

if($node = node_submit($node)) { // Prepare node for saving
    node_save($node);
}
```

note - when I add the same information through the content type form everthing works fine. It's almost as if my code is missing something that helps connect it to views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I found it. you need $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;

without it, Drupal does not have a language to assign it too. If you have local enabled, then $node->language has to equal 'en' or whatever your langauge is you're creating a link for.

Comment: does this setting have a module setting interface equivalent, one that I can set from the view settings, for instance?

Comment: views has a language selection setting, yes, but that would not be related to what I was trying to accomplish here, I don't think. Ask a question about what you're trying to do and maybe I can help answer.

Comment: I made my comment into a question: [Views: Using pathauto url alias in link fields](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85685/views-using-the-pathouto-url-alias-in-link-fields)

Answer (score 0):

Views doesn't see the alias.  When Drupal receives an alias URL, the first thing it does is change the URL to the default.  Views does not come into the process until after the URL is changed, so it does not know about the alias.