# Views link fields are not using Pathauto URL aliases for authenticated user

Tags: views, path-aliases

I am using some views fields as links to the main content. To make the links use the content URL aliases I have:

- Added NID as a field, excluded it from display, and moved it to top of
  the list
- In the "Rewrite results" section of the field I want to use as a link,
  I checked "Output this field as link" and for the link path, I
  entered `node/[nid]`.

as explained [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/85689/3366).

This seemed to work fine.

But when you visit the site as an authenticated user, these link fields start to display the `node/[nid]` style URLs.

The URL aliases are still working even for the authenticated user. The title field in a given view for instance, has the aliased path for the href and the link works. But the fields I made into a link with `node/[nid]` token are not aliased.

I have tried deleting and updating the aliases and clearing the caches. Although not really related, I also tried to turn on and off the "ignore admin path" option in the [Global Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module settings. Nothing changes as the problem is not limited with the admin pages.

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can solve this?

Comment: when you try to aliased path what you see?

Comment: @zhilevan, the aliased path is working. The title field for instance, has the aliased path for the href. But the fields I made into a link with node/[nid] token are not aliased.

Comment: Do you Try `clear cache`?

Comment: @zhilevan, considering your comments, I edited the question.